# UnsolvableVersionConflictException updating apache beam version

Tags: java, maven, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Currently I'm using apache beam 2.18.0 within GCP (Dataflow) and I would like to update it to 2.20.0

The problem is I have the following error if I use 2.20.0 instead of 2.18.0 in my pom file:

```
Caused by: org.eclipse.aether.collection.UnsolvableVersionConflictException: Could not resolve version conflict among [com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:1.56.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-stub:jar:1.28.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.28.1, com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:1.56.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-auth:jar:1.28.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:[1.28.1,1.28.1], com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:1.56.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.28.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.28.1, com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:1.56.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-protobuf:jar:1.28.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-protobuf-lite:jar:1.28.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.28.1, com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:1.56.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-netty-shaded:jar:1.28.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-core:jar:[1.28.1,1.28.1] -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:[1.28.1,1.28.1], com.google.cloud:google-cloud-kms:jar:1.38.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.28.1, com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore:jar:1.102.4 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.28.1, org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:jar:2.20.0 -> com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigquerystorage:jar:0.120.1-beta -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.25.0, org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:jar:2.20.0 -> com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-client-core:jar:1.13.0 -> com.google.cloud:google-cloud-bigtable:jar:1.9.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.26.0, org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:jar:2.20.0 -> com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-client-core:jar:1.13.0 -> com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-cloud-bigtable-v2:jar:1.9.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.26.0, org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:jar:2.20.0 -> com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-client-core:jar:1.13.0 -> com.google.api.grpc:grpc-google-cloud-bigtable-admin-v2:jar:1.9.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.26.0, org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:jar:2.20.0 -> com.google.cloud.bigtable:bigtable-client-core:jar:1.13.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.26.0, org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:jar:2.20.0 -> com.google.cloud:google-cloud-core-grpc:jar:1.92.2 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.26.0, org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:jar:2.20.0 -> com.google.cloud:google-cloud-spanner:jar:1.49.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.26.0, org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:jar:2.20.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-all:jar:1.25.0 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:[1.25.0,1.25.0]]
```

I have seen other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60662804/issues-with-maven-dependencies-unsolvableversionconflictexception) with a similar problem but I can not see any relation with apache beam.

Which dependency should I add or remove?

This is how my pom file looks like:

```
<modules>
...
</modules>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
    <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>

    <beam.version>2.18.0</beam.version>

    <maven-compiler-plugin.version>3.7.0</maven-compiler-plugin.version>
    <maven-exec-plugin.version>1.6.0</maven-exec-plugin.version>
    <maven-jar-plugin.version>3.1.2</maven-jar-plugin.version>
    <slf4j.version>1.7.25</slf4j.version>
    ...
</properties>

<repositories>
    ...
</repositories>

<dependencyManagement>
    ...
</dependencyManagement>

<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
    </plugins>

    <pluginManagement>
        ...
    </pluginManagement>
</build>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-storage</artifactId>
        <version>1.101.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-direct-java</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
        <artifactId>gax-grpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.49.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-kms</artifactId>
        <version>1.34.0</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>google-cloud-core-grpc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>google-cloud-datastore</artifactId>
        <version>1.102.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-core</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
                <artifactId>gax-grpc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                <artifactId>grpc-core</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-extensions-google-cloud-platform-core</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
                <artifactId>gax-grpc</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-sdks-java-io-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.beam</groupId>
        <artifactId>beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java</artifactId>
        <version>${beam.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.json</groupId>
        <artifactId>json</artifactId>
        <version>20190722</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-jdk14</artifactId>
        <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
        <artifactId>auto-value</artifactId>
        <version>${autovalue.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.auto.value</groupId>
        <artifactId>auto-value-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>${autovalue.annotations.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud.sql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgres-socket-factory</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.13</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.2.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.zaxxer</groupId>
        <artifactId>HikariCP</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
        <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.12</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.opencensus</groupId>
        <artifactId>opencensus-api</artifactId>
        <version>0.25.0</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
        <artifactId>hamcrest-all</artifactId>
        <version>1.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.jcraft</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsch</artifactId>
        <version>0.1.55</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

If I exclude the following:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.google.api</groupId>
     <artifactId>gax-grpc</artifactId>
        <version>1.49.0</version>
          <exclusions>
             <exclusion>
                <groupId>io.grpc</groupId>
                  <artifactId>grpc-api</artifactId>
             </exclusion>
           </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

The error about the dependency disappears, but, If I do that, I can not finish the compilation of the project because I get the following error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.cache.CacheBuilder.expireAfterWrite(Ljava/time/Duration;)Lcom/google/common/cache/CacheBuilder;
```

Comment: taking a look at this tomorrow!

Comment: can you share what GCP-related dependencies  you have in your pom.xml?

Answer (score 0):

So looking at the message, you have these three groups of dependencies that seem to be conflicting:

```
com.google.api:gax-grpc:jar:1.56.0 -> (...) -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.28.1
```

```
com.google.cloud:google-cloud-kms:jar:1.38.1 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.28.1
com.google.cloud:google-cloud-datastore:jar:1.102.4 -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.28.1
```

```
org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:jar:2.20.0 -> (...) -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.25.0
org.apache.beam:beam-sdks-java-io-google-cloud-platform:jar:2.20.0 -> (...) -> io.grpc:grpc-api:jar:1.26.0
```

So it seems that you need to match up those three groups (`gax-grpc`, `google-cloud-kms`, `google-cloud-datastore`).

You could use dependencyManagement to force `grpc-api` and `grpc-core` versions around a single one (1.26.0 or perhaps 1.28.1)...

Comment: I have seen here [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53472665/10346701) that this kind of error could be due some inconsistency between the Apache Beam and Google but I still don't get the solution. Should I exclude something within a  dependency? In which dependency should I exclude what?